# Trouble in rewiring a 4-way after removing transformer that was connected to the middle box

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Previously, I had a low-voltage single light fixture controlled by three switches. However, I recently replaced it with a regular fixture, eliminating the need for the transformer.
Unfortunately, I neglected to take a picture of the original wiring configuration before making the switch, and now I'm unsure how to properly connect the wires between Switch Box 2 and Switch Box 3 to restore functionality.

Here's what I can recall about the original setup:

- Switch Box 1: 3-way switch, 14/3 wire, and 14/2 wire leading to the light fixture.
- Switch Box 2: 4-way switch, 14/3 wire from Box 1, 12/2 wire to the transformer and Switch Box 3, and another 14/3 wire to Switch Box 3.
- Switch Box 3: 14/3 wire from Box 2, 3-way switch, and 14/2 wire from Box 2.

My understanding is that for the current setup to function correctly, power needs to reach the 3-way switches. I would be incredibly grateful if you could provide guidance on how to connect the wires between Switch Box 2 and Switch Box 3 in this new configuration.

[image]

Comment: This is way above what I can help with, but are the whites at box 2 and 3 connected together or capped off?  Box 1 shows them connected, the other two boxes they are in the air.  Do not know how they should be, wait for an expert, but the experts might want to know.

Comment: The 2 white wires from the 14/3 wires are connected together in box 2. The 12/2 is open ended in box 2 and box 3. Feel like a dead wire between the 2 boxes. Not too sure how to wire it in box 2 if needed.

Comment: You do not show the power in cable.  Possible it is the 14/2 so if the white is not connected, then no power.

Comment: I checked, the white wires are connected from (two) 14/3  wires has power in box 2. And the white wire from 14/3 in box 3 also has power. I’m sure there is a purpose for 14/2 wire, just not too sure yet. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6):

### Based on your diagram, you just have to hook up the neutrals (and grounds, if you haven't already gotten it)

Assuming your diagram is correct, it looks like you have all the hot wires taken care of, and just have to deal with neutrals and grounds now.  Fortunately, it shouldn't be hard to deal with: just connect the two white wires from the /3 cables to each other in Box 2, then connect the two white wires in Box 3 to each other, and last but not least connect all the grounds together in the boxes if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! I've attached the updated diagram for your reference. I'm still uncertain about the 14/2 wire in box 2—it seems to be a link between box 2 and box 3 without any power. Any insights on its purpose would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again for your assistance!  file:///var/mobile/Library/SMS/Attachments/42/02/2F11BBBE-BEB7-4340-979E-D9F1772E2548/image0.jpg

Comment: @BillChen -- your updated diagram didn't attach

Comment: Not too sure how attached diagram/picture. Still learning…

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq6yD.jpg (updated diagram)

Comment: @BillChen can you provide photos of the insides of boxes 2 and 3 please?

Comment: @BillChen The cable you're asking about is presumably the link back to your panel (unless it actually terminates in box 2?).  Power has to get to this light somehow, so something has to connect to the rest of your house's wiring.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Here are pictures of the layouts for boxes #2 and #3. Some wires have been pulled out or disconnected for better visibility. Thanks again for your help!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFLKB.jpg (box #2)
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe031.jpg (box #3)

Comment: @Miles Budnek  Agree. Since the transformer used to be connected to box 2, it seems like the power source must originate from within box 2. I tested the 14/2 wire with a voltage tester, but the light stayed off. I’m stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I'm fairly certain I see what's up now. Just saw the photos you have box 2 and 3.  I will draw out connections for you. Box 2: the single pole switch on right was the missing information. I believe that one of the 14/2 wires stretched to the right is the wire you didn't know for sure what to do with and the red jumper wire was existing; you just replaced a wire nut with the wago. Connect the black going to box 3 into that wago with the red and black wire. That will be your line in. The white tires in with the other 2 whites on the right. In box 3, connect 2 whites together and connect black wire from 14/2 to common on switch. That will do it!
[image: box3]
[image: box2]

Comment: You're right! The key step was getting power from box 3 to box 2. I ended up taking power from the other switch in box 3, wiring it as a common wire, and pigtailed it to the common screw on the 3-way switch. Then, wired the rest of the wirings in both box 2 and box 3 as you described. Thanks a ton for all your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

The key step was getting power from box 3 to box 2. I ended up taking power from the other switch in box 3, wiring it as a common wire, and pigtailed it to the common screw on the 3-way switch. Then, wired the rest of the wirings in both box 2 and box 3 as described by Keith.